# Is this equality true? (cauchy integral + green's theorem)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, stokes-theorem, greens-theorem

Is this just TRUE?

$$\oint_{\partial S} f(z) \, dz = i\iint_S \bigg[\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{x}}+i \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{y}}\bigg] \, dx \, dy$$

Because I'm using it without a proof, and I am finding an absurd! I hope the error is in here.

Comment: Let $f(z)=z$ on $S=\{z:~|z|<1\}$.

Comment: We need appropriate assumptions on $S$ and $f$, but if $S$ and $f$ are sufficiently regular, it's just Stokes's theorem (the general version for differential forms, which includes the classical Gauß's, Green's, and Stokes's theorems; I think in classical terms it's Green's one here).